# Want pause for 5 sec in deleting files from fold

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am running a window script to delete files from folder which have around 10k files .I want that my script command which is:

```
forfiles /p "path" /s /d -30 /c "cmd /c del @file : date >= 30 days >NUL"
```

,should delete 10 files and then wait for 5 sec and then again start deleting and then again wait for `5 secons` and so on?
I want this feature because if 10k files are deleted in one go , it will create hamper the normal working of server

Comment: write clearly you question. If you want to pause inside batch, use `timeout /t <secondes>`

Comment: The problem is probably the command you're using, `ForFiles`. When it runs it opens a new `cmd.exe` instance for each matching file. So you are effectively opening `cmd.exe`, deleting one file and closing `cmd.exe` 10000 times. Also for your information, I would have suggested you use `@path` instead of `@file` and remove everything after it except for the closing doublequote because it's not valid.

Comment: Try This : `timeout /T 5 /nobreak`

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to achieve

```
timeout /T 5
```

With older Windows OS', *(pre-Vista)*, where `timeout` is not available, you can simply use `ping` to do the wait. There is a second delay between each echo request, so for 5 seconds we need 6 `ping` counts. So by running the below it will wait 5 seconds.

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 >nul
```

To give you an idea how to do the delete you can do something like below: (I am using `echo`, but you can loop a `del` instead).

```
:start
for /L %%G IN (1,1,10) DO echo "Some command"
timeout /T 5
goto start
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use a different command from `ForFiles` and run the script without pauses or the need to split the number of files into smaller chunks.

This uses `RoboCopy` with its `/Move` option:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "_source=C:\Users\Sumit-Anand\Folder"
Set "_daysage=30"

Set "_scratch=%TEMP%\~%random%"
MD "%_scratch%"
RoboCopy "%_source%" "%_scratch%" /E /Move /Create /MinAge:%_daysage%
RD /S/Q "%_scratch%"
```

All you need to change is the value strings for the variables on lines `3` and `4`, making sure that you **do not** remove the closing doublequote or include any doublequotes with your new string.